# How to optimize two partitions at the same time under non linear constraints?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization

Let :

- $G$ be a undirected graph with nodes $a_1, \ldots, a_n$
- $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ a set of real values
- $\epsilon > 0$
- Var the variance function
- $d$ the "distance" between sets : $d(X_1, X_2) = \min_{x_1\in X_1, x_2\in X_2, x_1\neq x_2} |x_1-x_2|$. It's not exactly a distance.

I'm looking at finding :

- $k\in\mathbb{N}$
- a partition of the nodes $(a_i)_i$ in sets $G_1, \ldots, G_k$
- a partition of the $(x_i)_i$ in sets $F_1, \ldots, F_k$

such that it maximizes :
$$
\sum_j Var(F_j)
$$
under the following constraints :

- For any edge $(a_1, a_2)$ of $G$, denoting $G_i$ and $G_j$ the groups containing $a_1$ and $a_2$, we require that $d(F_i, F_j) > \epsilon$
- For all $i$, $|F_i| \geq |G_i|$

How to optimize two partitions at the same time under non-linear constraints?

Comment: Are you requiring that no edge in $G$ be within a single group?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: So if $(a_1, a_2)$ is an edge with $a_1$ and $a_2$ both in $G_i$, then you require $d(F_i, F_i) > \epsilon$? That's a problem.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the "distance" because I didn't describe well the case you described

Comment: So you want $d(X, X) = \min_{x_1 \in X, x_2 \in X, x_1\neq x_2} \vert x_1 - x_2\vert$? (Note that both arguments of the distance function are the same, i.e., we are talking about the distance of a set from itself.)

Comment: Using variance as your dispersion measure is going to complicate the model, and maximizing it is going to be a problem because it means maximizing a convex function. Would another dispersion measure (say the sum of the set diameters) serve as well?

Comment: Another measure of dispersion is good too

Comment: $d(X, X) = \min_{x_1\in X, x_2\in X, x_1\neq x_2} |x_1-x_2|$ yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest/most tractable dispersion measure I can think of is set
diameter (maximum absolute difference between two elements of the
set), and even then the model (a mixed integer linear program) is
going to be rather large.

In what follows, indices $h$ and $i$ will select either numbers
(e.g., $x_{h}$) or vertices (e.g., $a_{h}$) while indices $j$ and
$\ell$ will select sets of numbers (e.g., $F_{j}$) or sets of vertices
(e.g., $G_{j}$). So the range of $h$ and $i$ will be either 1 to
$m$ or 1 to $n$, depending on context. The range of $j$ and $\ell$
will be 1 to $K$, where $K$ is an *a priori* bound on the number
of sets to use in the partition. The actual number $k$ of sets used
will be determined from the final solution by dropping empty sets.
$M$ will be a sufficiently large positive number. (It need not be
the same in every constraint, but I will omit subscripts to spare
myself some typing.) $E$ represents the set of edges in $G.$

The model will contain the following variables:

- binary $y_{ij}$ will be 1 if number $x_{i}$ belongs to set $F_{j}$,
  0 if not;
- binary $u_{ij}$ will be 1 if vertex $a_{i}$ belongs to set $G_{j}$,
  0 if not;
- binary $v_{hij}$ will be 1 if numbers $x_{h}$ and $x_{i}$ ($h<i$)
  both belong to $F_{j}$ and determine the diameter of $F_{j}$ (i.e.,
  are the furthest apart of any pair of numbers in $F_{j};$
- real $z_{j\ell}\ge0$ will be the distance $d(F_{j},F_{\ell})$ between
  sets $j$ and $\ell$; and
- real $w_{j}\ge0$ will be the diameter of set $F_{j}.$

The objective function will be to maximize $\sum_{j}w_{j}.$ The constraints
are as follows.

- Every number belongs to exactly one of the $F$ sets.
  $$\sum_{j}y_{ij}=1\quad\forall i.$$
- Every node belongs to exactly one of the $G$ sets.
  $$\sum_{j}u_{ij}=1\quad\forall i.$$
- The cardinality of each $F_{j}$ is at least as large as the cardinality
  of the corresponding $G_{j}$.
  $$\sum_{i}y_{ij}\ge\sum_{i}u_{ij}\quad\forall j.$$
  Note that this prevents using a set $G_{j}$ while leaving $F_{j}$
  empty.
- You cannot use $F_{j}$ while leaving $G_{j}$ empty.
  $$y_{ij}\le\sum_{h}u_{hj}\quad\forall i,j.$$
  Combined with the previous constraint, this ensures that the number
  of sets $F_{\cdot}$ and the number of sets $G_{\cdot}$ that are
  used will be the same ($k$).
- The distance between two sets is at most the minimum distance between
  (distinct) members of each set.
  $$z_{j\ell}\le\vert x_{h}-x_{i}\vert+M\left(2-y_{hj}-y_{i\ell}\right)\quad\forall j\le\ell,\forall h\neq i.$$
  Note that this constraint is repeated for both $h<i$ and $h>i$.
- For any edge in the graph, the distance between the number sets corresponding to the vertex sets containing the endpoints of the edge must be at least $\epsilon$.
  $$z_{j\ell}\ge\epsilon\left(u_{hj}+u_{i\ell}-1\right)\quad\forall j\le\ell,\forall h\neq i\ni(a_{h},a_{i})\in E.$$
  Note that this constraint is repeated for both $(a_{h},a_{i})$ and
  $(a_{i},a_{h}).$
- For $v_{hij}$ to be 1, it is necessary that both $x_{h}$ and $x_{i}$
  belong to $F_{j}$.
  $$v_{hij}\le y_{hj}\quad\forall h<i,\forall j.$$
  $$v_{hij}\le y_{ij}\quad\forall h<i,\forall j.$$
- Exactly one pair of numbers dictates the diameter of $F_{j}$.
  $$\sum_{h,i:h<i}v_{hij}=1\quad\forall j.$$
- The diameter of $F_{j}$ is determined by the $v_{\cdot\cdot j}$
  variables.
  $$w_{j}=\sum_{h,i:h<i}\vert x_{h}-x_{i}\vert v_{hij}\quad\forall j.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot !!